# Reform and Duplicate javascript object due to size of inner array

Tags: javascript, json

I have following json object

```
const paresdData = [
    {
        "name": "Mathilda",
        "Infotypes": [
            {
                "Infotype": "9000",
                "InfotypeCanonicalName": "AdditionalFieldsInfotype",
                "AdditionalFieldsInfotype": {
                    "CompanyCode": "2303",
                }
            },
            {
                "Infotype": "0000",
                "InfotypeCanonicalName": "Actions",
                "Actions": [
                    {
                        "StartDate": "20121212",
                        "ActionType": "01",
                    },
                    {
                        "StartDate": "20230401",
                        "ActionType": "02",
                    }
                ]
            }
       ]
    }
]

parsedData.forEach((data) => {
             data.Infotypes.forEach( (Infotype) => {
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(Infotype, 'Actions') && Infotype.Actions.length > 1) {
                     Infotype.Actions.forEach( (action) => {
                // Add the logic here

                })
                }
            })
        })
```

I want to have a logic to check if paresdData.Infotypes.Actions array has more than one object then:

1. duplicate the content of paresdData object to be same length as paresdData.Infotypes.Actions array length.
2. paresdData.Infotypes.Actions array length should be equal to 1, where it the first one will be assigned to first object and second to the second object of paresdData and so on..

so final updatedParedData should be like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Mathilda",
        "Infotypes": [
            {
                "Infotype": "9000",
                "InfotypeCanonicalName": "AdditionalFieldsInfotype",
                "AdditionalFieldsInfotype": {
                    "CompanyCode": "2303",
                }
            },
            {
                "Infotype": "0000",
                "InfotypeCanonicalName": "Actions",
                "Actions": [
                    {
                        "StartDate": "20121212",
                        "ActionType": "01",
                    }
                ]
            }
       ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Mathilda",
        "Infotypes": [
            {
                "Infotype": "9000",
                "InfotypeCanonicalName": "AdditionalFieldsInfotype",
                "AdditionalFieldsInfotype": {
                    "CompanyCode": "2303",
                }
            },
            {
                "Infotype": "0000",
                "InfotypeCanonicalName": "Actions",
                "Actions": [
                    {
                        "StartDate": "20230401",
                        "ActionType": "02",
                    }
                ]
            }
       ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new array updatedParsedData and use nested loops to iterate over the existing parsedData and duplicate the objects based on the length of the Actions array. Please try with this code below.

```js
const updatedParsedData = [];

parsedData.forEach((data) => {
  data.Infotypes.forEach((infotype) => {
    if (
      Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(infotype, 'Actions') &&
      infotype.Actions.length > 1
    ) {
      infotype.Actions.forEach((action) => {
        const clonedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(parsedData));
        const clonedInfotype = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(infotype));
        clonedInfotype.Actions = [action];
        clonedData[0].Infotypes.splice(1, 0, clonedInfotype);
        updatedParsedData.push(clonedData[0]);
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log(updatedParsedData);
```

And please let me know if it works as you need.

Comment: yes it woks exactly due to my question, but I tried to develop the case by adding to else block in case if was false like this: elese{data)} but it didn't give correct result at all